# MobileCloudSDK without CoreLocation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, sdk

Apple is now requiring all apps that reference `CoreLocation` APIs to include the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key on `Info.plist` explaining why the location framework is being used.

When I uploaded my app to the App Store, I got this e-mail from Apple:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "[my app name]". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> **Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File** - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

Analysing all of our dependencies, I narrowed down MarketingCloudSDK as the sole responsible for including such references to the `CoreLocation` API.

Following Apple's recommendations, I'd like to request access to a version of the SDK that do not include location features.

I am currently using `MarketingCloudSDK` v6.2.0 via CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

@Guilherme, I will create a ticket in our system to look into the best way to handle this - thank you for posting here.

To confirm - your solution is not using the MobilePush location messaging feature at all, correct?

Brian

Comment: Thanks Brian. Right now, we do not use any of the location-related features from the SDK, but Apple requires the string because they can't know that the features are not used. From their perspective, they may eventually be used, therefore they expect a string.