# MarketingCloudSDK without CoreLocation (duplicate?)

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm not permitted to comment on that thread, so here's a duplicate and an update request on [MobileCloudSDK without CoreLocation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260100/mobilecloudsdk-without-corelocation)

I have tried to set "location" to false in the MarketingCloudSDKConfiguration.json, but Apple still complains about the missing NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription parameter.

Any update to when or if you can fix this, or if we have to provide that description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the SDK is built with references to CoreLocation, there's no way around Apple's automated scanning at submission - they're looking at the link dependencies and cross-referencing against your Info.plist without knowing about how the code paths to get there work.

Even if not used, an app consuming any code referencing CoreLocation will be required to have the plist entries.

However, they won't ever show unless your code triggers something to start watching location.

Thanks,

Brian